# ConcurrentModificationException despite the using Iterator and synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, iterator, listiterator

```
public class RetryHandler extends Thread {

private ArrayList<RetryMessage> retryMessages;
private Object syncObject = new Object();

private RetryHandler() {
    this.setName("retryhlr");
}
public Boolean addMessage(IfgExchangeRequestBase msg, int token) {
    synchronized(syncObject) {
        retryMessages.add(new RetryMessage(msg, token));
        return true;
    }
}

public Boolean removeMessage(Integer token) {
    synchronized(syncObject) {
        retryMessages.removeIf(x->x.getToken().equals(token));  
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(isRunning) {
        if (!isPaused) {
            synchronized(syncObject) {
                ListIterator<RetryMessage> tempRTMessages = retryMessages.listIterator();
                while(tempRTMessages.hasNext()){
                    RetryMessage rtmsg =tempRTMessages.next(); 
                    if(....)) {
                        tempRTMessages.remove();
                    } else if(...)
                        try {
                            int token = fetch()
                            rtmsg.retried();
                            rtmsg.setToken(token);
                        } catch (SAGException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

As you see RetryHandler extends Thread which iterating over a internal list `retryMessages`. Despite the using `Iterator` and `synchronized` i 'm getting  `ConcurrentModificationException`. `addMessage` and `removeMessage` has been used in other `Threads`.

**note:** I Used **ListIterator** but result is same. and `RetryMessage rtmsg =tempRTMessages.next();` raises this exception.
[image]

**UPDATE:** Exception raises on `RetryMessage rtmsg =tempRTMessages.next();`

Comment: Are you sure the `retryMessages` `List` is only modified via the `addMessage` and `removeMessage` methods?

Comment: What does `fetch()` do?

Comment: Note that it's a good idea to synchronize on final members, so that you can't accidentally reassign it.

Comment: @Eran: as you can see in code `retryMessages ` items change in `rtmsg.setToken(token)`

Comment: @Andy : It returns a number

Comment: Where is `retryMessages` initialized? Can another thread/task get a reference of `retryMessages`? Could you provide a working example to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @SubOptimal: constructor/No/ This is a running example, just another thread which calls `addMessage` and `removeMessage`

Comment: To avoid such a condition, you can also add "objects to remove" to a temp list, and use removeAll method on the primary list, after iteration is finished.

Comment: Add which place `retryMessages` is assigned with a list. Your posted code snippet currently would fail with a NullPointerException as soon you would access a property of `retryMessages` or call a method on it.

Comment: This is not a running example, we cannot simply copy this code and run it.

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering the error because of the exception because you are iterating the ArrayList, and while iterating it, you are removing objects from it. This is a fail fast mechanism for this type of collection.

What you can do if you really need to remove items from the ArrayList, is to create a CopyOnWriteArrayList object, this object is the one you will . Please see the code below:

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<RetryMessage> retryMessageCopyOnWrite= new CopyOnWriteArrayList<RetryMessage>(retryMessages);
    Iterator<RetryMessage> retryMessageIterator = retryMessageCopyOnWrite.iterator();
...
<some object modifications here for retryMessageCopyOnWrite>
```

Then just copy the content of the CopyOnWriteArrayList to the retryMessages list object back to the original arrayList.

```
retryMessages = new ArrayList<RetryMessage>(retryMessageCopyOnWrite);
```

Since you are also using the iterator itself to remove an item. Please read this link:
[CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://www.baeldung.com/java-copy-on-write-arraylist)

I suggest an alternative way to modify the list, instead of using the iterator itself, use the CopyOnWriteArrayList object.

You can have something like this inside the iteration:

```
RetryMessage temp = iterator.next();
if(do some checking) {
    retryMessageCopyOnWrite.remove(temp); //this removes the current element
}
```

Comment: why Iterator<String>`` ?

Comment: I changed it to Iterator<RetryMessage>

Comment: I changed my code but :
`Exception in thread "retryhlr" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$COWIterator.remove(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:1176)
 at RetryHandler.run(RetryHandler.java:98)`

Comment: exactly on ìt.remove();`